# Making random rectangles on Processing

Tags: java, for-loop, processing

I want to make random rectangles on Processing. So far, I used for loops for making window size rectangle but I can't figure out how to make only 10 rectangle randomly. Here is my sample code for you:

```
void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0); // Black Background

  stroke(255); // White lines

  for (int j = 0; j <= height; j += 40)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i += 40)
    {
      fill(0); 
      rect(i, j, 40, 40);
    }
  }
}
```

It shows 100 black rectangles but I want to see only 10 black rectangles. For example: The first line will get random 1 rectangle, second line will get 2 , third line will get 1 and it goes till the 10.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you are trying here but I think that out of the 100 times you get into the inner loop you only want to create a rectangle 10 times. You could get maximum 10 by using Math.random in an if clause before deciding whether to create rectangle or not eg if (Math.random() * 10 == 1) and then keep a counter too that you check in the if clause to avoid > 10. But you might not get 10 with random, could be 9 or even less.

Comment: So probably better to turn this round a bit - iterate 10 times, use random to get coordinates each time by multiplying by 400

Comment: But also keep track of where rectangles have been placed so you can retry if random coordinates will overlap an existing rectangle

Comment: A little complex but interesting, best to extract the list of existing rectangle coordinates to a separate class so you can have a method like willOverlap(x,y,width, height) that you call in a loop each time you come out with potential coordinates

Comment: Hello @Chris Thank you for your all effot for answering me but Math method can't usable on processing and also the method of willOverlap can't usable :/

Comment: Start with changing your loop, because your problem description is in terms of rows and columns: at each row `j`, you want `j` rectangles, so use `for (int j=0; j < COL_COUNT; j++) { ... }` with a `final int COL_COUNT` that you calculate by by seeing how many times you can fit your rectangle's desired width in your sketch's total width

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this fun homework/exercise.

First thing is drawing the right number of boxes per column:

```
void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);

  background(0); // Black Background
  fill(0);
  stroke(255); // White lines

  int boxSize = 40;
  int maxBoxes = 1;

  for (int j = 0; j <= height; j += boxSize)
  {
    // box count per row
    int boxCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i += boxSize)
    {
      // only draw the max number of boxes
      if(boxCount < maxBoxes){

        rect(i, j, 40, 40);
        // increment per row box count
        boxCount++;
      }
    }
    // increment max boxes per box
    maxBoxes++;
  }
}
```

Secondly the positions for the drawn boxes per column need to be randomized, but ideally not overlap. One option is to split the full solution space to sections: each section having it's own range of positions so it won't overlap the next.

```
void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);

  background(0); // Black Background
  fill(0);
  stroke(255); // White lines

  int boxSize = 40;
  int maxBoxes = 1;
  int totalBoxes = width / boxSize;

  for (int j = 0; j <= height; j += boxSize)
  {
    // box count per row
    int boxCount = 0;
    // a list of box indices of where to draw a box (as opposed
    int[] randomXIndices = new int[maxBoxes];
    // how many index ranges to span per row
    int indexRangePerBox = totalBoxes / maxBoxes;
    // for each random index 
    for(int k = 0 ; k < maxBoxes; k++)
    {
      // pre-calculate which random index to select
      // using separate ranges per box to avoid overlaps
      randomXIndices[k] = (int)random(indexRangePerBox * k, indexRangePerBox * (k + 1));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i += boxSize)
    {
      // only draw the max number of boxes
      if(boxCount < maxBoxes)
      {

        int randomX = randomXIndices[boxCount] * boxSize;

        rect(randomX, j, 40, 40);
        // increment per row box count
        boxCount++;
      }

    }
    // increment max boxes per box
    maxBoxes++;
  }
}

void draw(){
}

void mousePressed(){
  setup();
}
```

Click to reset. Notice that the bottom rows almost always look the same:

1. there is less wiggle room to pick a random position
2. `random()` is a rough pseudo-random number generator, but there are better ones out there like [`randomGaussian()`](https://processing.org/reference/randomGaussian_.html), [`noise()`](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html), etc.
3. overall there are other strategies to explore picking random positions and avoiding overlaps

Live demo bellow:

```js
function setup()
{
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  reset();
  // reset once per second
  setInterval(reset, 1000);
}

function reset(){
  background(0); // Black Background
  fill(0);
  stroke(255); // White lines
  
  var boxSize = 40;
  var maxBoxes = 1;
  var totalBoxes = width / boxSize;
  
  for (var j = 0; j <= height; j += boxSize)
  {
    // box count per row
    var boxCount = 0;
    // a list of box indices of where to draw a box (as opposed
    var randomXIndices = new Array(maxBoxes);
    // how many index ranges to span per row
    var indexRangePerBox = totalBoxes / maxBoxes;
    // for each random index 
    for(var k = 0 ; k < maxBoxes; k++)
    {
      // pre-calculate which random index to select
      // using separate ranges per box to avoid overlaps
      randomXIndices[k] = floor(random(indexRangePerBox * k, indexRangePerBox * (k + 1)));
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < width; i += boxSize)
    {
      // only draw the max number of boxes
      if(boxCount < maxBoxes)
      {
        
        var randomX = randomXIndices[boxCount] * boxSize;
        
        rect(randomX, j, 40, 40);
        // increment per row box count
        boxCount++;
      }
      
    }
    // increment max boxes per box
    maxBoxes++;
  }
}

function draw(){
}

function mousePressed(){
  reset();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: grid with less and less random positioned boxes]